# What is the meaning of the Regular Expression ^(.)\1+$

Tags: c#, regex, c#-4.0

Since I am new of regular expression I well versed with Regex.

Can someone please help with the meaning of this Regex?

^(.)\1+$

Comment: See here: http://regexr.com/3b9j0 (it repeats a character at least twice)

Comment: It means the string contains the exact same character, repeated 2 or more times.

Comment: If you can't read regex well, then this site is good for a basic idea of what the regex is meaning: http://www.myezapp.com/apps/dev/regexp/show.ws

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^(.)\1+$` is a clever regular expression that matches to any full line that has two or more letters all of which are identical.  E.g.:

- aaa
- BBBBBBB

See comments for explanation of what each part of the regular expression does.

Comment: Not the same answer because you forgot to say that it has to be the full line, given the ^ and $. :P

Comment: agree but technically it matches any characters not only letters :P

Comment: @AndriyHoren Ha ha! Damn the English technicality ;)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer:  The first character in the subject is repeated one or more times and occupies the entire test subject.  Put differently, the entire subject is occupied by two or more of the same character.

Since you're learning:

'^' is the begin of subject "anchor."  It does not consume any data, just asserts a position.  Similar to the metacharacter sequence \A if you encounter that, although the latter is not affected by line mode (research regex "mode modifiers").

'$' is the end of subject anchor.  Again, a non consuming assertion.  Similar to \Z metacharacter, although the latter is not affected by line mode.  Close cousin of \z (although the latter has no regard for newlines and line modes).  Anytime you see a regex framed with ^...$ it's asserting that the match condition is front to back.

"()" are capturing parenthesis.  This means you can "refer back" to what was captured using \N where N is 1-9 corresponding to the order of capturing parenthesis, left to right.  In your example, we only have one capture group, so it's referred to as \1.  In addition to capturing for reference, groups are used for quantification--for repeating a pattern a specified number of times, and for alternation of strings or patterns, e.g.:  (^*|*$), where "|" is a logical "or," this regex would test to see if the subject begins or ends with an underscore.

'.' (dot) is a metacharacter that represents any single character.  (Roughly speaking, look up various match "modes" to see how you can control whether or not dot matches line break.  Don't confuse "character" with octet or byte.  Locales and character set encodings are too grand a subject to elaborate, but just be aware that the definition of a "character" is somewhat contextual.)

'+' is the one-or-more quantifier.  \1+ means whatever character was captured by capture group 1 repeats one-or-more times (i.e., occurs two or more times).  "aa" would match, where the first 'a' is matched by the dot captured in group \1, and the second 'a' matches because it satisfies the one-or-more quantification.